# передать POST запрос в стандартный браузер андроид

Tags: android, post

Здравствуйте! Суть вопроса - в ответ на POST запрос сервер присылает страничку - нужно чтоб она открывалась уже в браузере по умолчанию на андроиде. 
Вижу два пути - либо в браузер как-то передавать POST запрос и дальше работать, либо получать страничку от сервера и ее уже передавать в браузер. Не знаю как можно реализовать ни то, ни другое. 
Если кто-то сталкивался подскажите пожалуйста. 
Работаю в андроид студио, POST запрос передаю с помощью HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Есть много путей этого достичь, простых и сложных. Расскажите подробнее про задачу, мне кажется тут есть более правильное решение. МОжете привести пример запроса на сервер и ответа?

Answer (score 1):

В *браузере* открыть точно не получится, можно открыть в `WebView`:

```
webView.loadData(yourHtmlPageString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

или

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(www.<ваш сайт, куда отправляли пост запрос>, yourHtmlPageString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Если получаешь адрес страницы, то делай так

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("адрес страницы")));
```